# Files empty after moving with FTP

Tags: themes, ftp

I have a strange bug within my Wordpress theme.

After I copy normal files from my local machine (whatever file, functions.php, styles.css or any other) the file gets empty on the server, with no content and I can see the size of 0mb.

On the backend, wp-admin works normally, I have previousely received some caching error but that its.

Any ideas?

P.s. I am using WP 3.1

Comment: Are you using an FTP client like FileZilla or WordPress FTP functionality?

Comment: Maybe it's some quota error? Sometimes I get similar behavior, when I try to upload files with FTP and my FTP user has used all space available for him. FTP client is able to create file, but it can't write to this file.